# Raspbian - Putty(Windows) Interface. X-Display doesn't work with root user

Tags: putty, raspberry-pi, raspbian, xming

I can transfer display with Xming and Putty successfully with my user "pi" but not with the "root" user. It gives me the error:

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol
```

Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 2):

For me this was fixed adding the following to my users ~/.ssh/config file:

```
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Comment: After this i also had to copy the xauth from my user to the root user like described [here](http://superuser.com/a/912700/458656) to get rid of the Authorisation not recognised

Answer (score 0):

`root` login is intentionally disabled by default.

You should login as `pi` and `sudo` to do root tasks.  See the [raspbian FAQ](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#How_do_I_make_a_proper_root_account.3F) for more information.