# How do I solve the "PuTTY X11 proxy: No authorisation provided" error?

Tags: command-line, firefox, putty, x11-forwarding

I am trying to run firefox on a remote server over ssh and use X11 forwarding to open the window on my laptop, but when I try to it throws the "PuTTY X11 proxy: No authorisation provided" error. I cannot find any reference to this error anywhere, and the only mention remotely close to it is here: [Error Putty X11 proxy: Authorisation not recognised](https://superuser.com/questions/912669/error-putty-x11-proxy-authorisation-not-recognised) and none of these solutions helped at all. I can run most X11 applications, which is the reason I am bringing this here. I have tried xeyes, xclock, gedit, and netsurf, and all work completely fine. The problem is whenever I open firefox (or midori or browsh) I get this error. The full error is below:

```
PuTTY X11 proxy: No authorisation provided
Error: cannot open display: server:10.0
```

I am aware that "no authorization" has been provided to X11, but I do not know what authorization it wants or needs or on what end.

For reference, I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on the remote end and windows 11 on my laptop.

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu, or some other distro that uses Snap for Firefox?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, I forgot to mention it, I'll add it to the post.